# Actionevent final variables?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have the following code and i get an error at line 19 "cannot assign a value to a final variable count", but i have to assign this variable as final in order to use it in the "LISTENER".  Where is the mistake ?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ButtonTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);

        final int count = 0;

        class ClickListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("I was clicked " + count + " times");
            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setSize(100,60);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A  `final` variable cannot be modified once it has been assigned. The solution is to make the variable a member of your ClickListener class:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ButtonTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);

        class ClickListener implements ActionListener
        {
            int count = 0;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("I was clicked " + count + " times");
            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setSize(100,60);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using count inside your `ClickListener` class, but it is declared outside of the class. You are only using it inside `ClickListener`, so move the declaration there. Might as well also make the class static:

```
    static class ClickListener implements ActionListener
    {
        private int count = 0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("I was clicked " + count + " times");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would have to pull it out of the main method, and declare it inside the `ButtonTester` class. Or if you have other code in it that you aren't showing, you might not be able to make it static. It's good practise to make nested classes static if possible. If you can't that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Move the variable inside the ClickListener, this is what you really want.
If you move the variable outside of the class it MUST be final because it will be treated like a constant.